# trying to define function to reverse string

Tags: c

I wrote this function to reverse a string in C but it doesn't work.

```
#define         MAXSIZE         30

char buffer[MAXSIZE] = "hello";
int main(void)
{
    strrev(buffer);
    printf("%s",buffer);
    return 0;
}

void strrev(char *s)
{
    char c = 0;
    char *ptr = s;
    while(*s)
        s++;
    char *f = s;
    while(ptr != f);
    {
        c = *ptr;
        *ptr = *s;
        *s = c;
        s--;
        ptr++;
    }
}
```

i can't find what's wrong whith that code

Comment: Time to learn to use a debugger. it will show you what is wrong.

Comment: Using your debugger, check what happens after `while(*s)`

Comment: I agree with Paul, try using the debugger or use printf to print out the values. Check your    while(*s)

Comment: infinite loop : while(ptr != f) **;** (extra semicolon)

Comment: `while(ptr!=f);` == `while(ptr!=f) { }`

Comment: Moreover, `f` is useless, `s` must be decremented, and the good condition must be `ptr < s`.

Comment: note for your future questions on SO (or for any other site / persons) : "doesn't work" is very vague: Try to give a more accurate description of the problem : the output is not the expected output ? An compilation error or a runtime exception happens ? other ? (in this case, the program doesn't stop and doesn't output anything), it will help other, and yourself to identify the problem more quickly (and you will also sound more professional if coding is your job ;) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues with you funcion.

1) `while(*s)
        s++;`
    Moves the pointer `s` to point to `\0`. So you need to point to the char before `\0` by doing `f=s-1;`

2) Remove the semicolon at the end of  `while(ptr != f)` and condition will not work if there is one more extra char in your `buffer` , so change it to `while(ptr < f)`

3) You should replace `*ptr = *s; *s = c; s--;` to `*ptr = *f; *f = c; f--;`

Comment: why when i use `s` as the first address of string doesn't work ?
but when i use `f` it works properly ?

Comment: @mohamedtarek I dont see any need for using additional variable `f` here.`while(*s)
        s++;
    s--;
    while(ptr != s);` should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `s--;` after `while(*s) s++;`. This is because *s will be '\0' after the loop.
2. Remove semicolon in the next while loop.

Answer (score 1):

There are many mistakes in your program :-

- You should have `function prototype`  before you call that function.
- `while(*s)` should be `while (*(s+1) != '\0')` ,till you reach last character.
- `while(ptr != f);` should be `while (ptr <= s)` you don't need that `;` and swapping chars upto `ptr <= s` is only needed.

So modified code:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXSIZE 30

char buffer[MAXSIZE] = "hello";

void strrev(char *s); // function prototype

int main(void)
{
    strrev(buffer);
    printf("%s", buffer);
    return 0;
}

void strrev(char *s)
{

    char c = 0;
    char *ptr = s;
    while (*(s + 1) != '\0')
    {
        s++;
    }
    char *f = s;
    while (ptr <= s)
    {
        c = *ptr;
        *ptr = *s;
        *s = c;
        s--;
        ptr++;
    }
}
```

**Output** *(gcc)* :-

```
olleh
```

Comment: Fails for empty string.

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Where does `*(s + 1)` point when s is `""`?